# Azure kubernetes - How to set up Azure App gateway and Azure API management for Azure kubernetes?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-api-management, azure-application-gateway

I have set up Azure API management in front of the Azure kubernetes application APIs and would like to place Azure App Gateway in front of the Azure API management, how would I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could refer to this doc - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-integrate-internal-vnet-appgateway

This article covers how to use a single API Management service for both internal and external consumers and make it act as a single frontend for both on premises and cloud APIs. You will also see how to expose only a subset of your APIs (in the example they are highlighted in green) for External Consumption using routing functionality available in Application Gateway.